# How can I determine tile clicked on in Isometric XYZ without colliders/gameobjects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, isometric

I'm working on an Isometric XYZ tile game. I am generating all the tiles from sprites at runtime. They do not have colliders attached. I'm trying to determine which tile a player is clicking on using Input.mousePosition. I have tried a ton of math, and nothing seems to work right. As I move away from the origin of the map (WorldPosition 0,0) my error increases. I have tried applying the math found in isometric tutorials and haven't gotten anywhere. There must be a way to do this, can anyone help?

Comment: Share the code/math please.

Comment: Please show the math, and are all your tiles co-planar (on same plane)? I imagine your process is something like: ```Screen Coord to Ray -> Intersect Plane -> Calculate tile from intersect point```?